# Definite article in front of plural or uncountable nouns

Tags: definite-article, plural-forms, zero-article, uncountable-nouns, noun-phrases

Please help! I'm totally confused whether to use or omit the definite article in front of plural or uncountable nouns. I'm writing a scientific article. Here is an excerpt (*N.B.*  ROS = reactive oxygen species, plural).

> (The?) studies investigating (the?) ROS production in (the?) primary T cells are
>   limited, especially (the?) studies in (the?) primary human T cells. Moreover,
>   (the?) majority of those studies employed (the?) highly artificial types of
>   (the?) stimulation, such as (the?) stimulations with (the?) PMA and (the?) ionomycin or (the?)
>   CD3 and (the?) CD28 antibodies added in (the?) solution, leading to (the?) T-cell
>   hyperactivation or (the?) unresponsiveness, respectively. There were also no
>   precautions taken to discriminate (the?) T cell-derived ROS from that
>   emanating from (the?) phagocytic cells, which are always present in (the?)
>   preparations of (the?) primary T cells and could be easily activated by (the?)
>   same stimulatory agents.

All I know is that for plural countable or uncountable nouns the rule is:

If a noun (**or noun phrase?**) refers to all of the group/entity – no article is required (word **typical** can be inserted)

If a noun (**or noun phrase?**) refers to a subset of the group/entity – **the** should be used (**those/that** can be inserted instead)

The major problem for me is to understand whether it is a noun **or a noun phrase** that must refer to a subset of a group, and whether the rest of the noun phrase can make noun to refer to a subset. For example,

> The studies investigating the ROS production in primary T cells are
>   limited, especially the studies in primary human T cells.

Here, **the studies** refer to a subset of studies devoted to *investigating the ROS production in primary T cells*. **The ROS production** refers to a subset of ROS production that occurs *in primary T cells*. On the other hand, **primary T cells** in this context are generic, so no article is required. Is my logic correct?

Or can it be that **studies investigating ROS production in primary T cells**, **studies in primary human T cells** and **ROS production in primary T cells** are also generic concepts, and hence do not require articles?

> Studies investigating ROS production in primary T cells are
>   limited, especially studies in primary human T cells.

Please help!

Comment: You've got some excellent example sentences there where the articles are by and large **optional**. They neither need to be included nor need to be omitted.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you! Can you please elaborate on it? How to define whether an article defines the noun or the noun phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that the use of the definite article with plural or uncountable nouns is not very strictly defined by grammatical rules, and decisions are left to the author.

However, I also came up with the following rule. I'm not saying I'm the first who came up with something like this, but it works for me like a charm.

> Try to insert ***any (kind of)*** or ***some (kind of)*** in front of the noun in question. If at least one of those
>   works, put ***a*** for singular countable or **no article** for plural countable and uncountable nouns. If none
>   work, put ***the***.

It does not work for proper nouns though, but that's another story.

Finally, I gravitated towards this version:

> There are few studies investigating ROS production in primary T cells,
>   especially in human primary T cells. Moreover, the
>   majority of those studies employed highly artificial types of
>   stimulation, such as stimulations with PMA and ionomycin, or with CD3
>   and CD28 antibodies added in solution, which lead to T-cell
>   hyperactivation or unresponsiveness, respectively. There were also no
>   precautions taken to discriminate the T cell-derived ROS from those
>   emanating from phagocytic cells, which are always present in
>   preparations of primary T cells and could be easily activated by the
>   same stimulatory agents.

Answer (score 2):

Preamble:  use the article (or not) to tell the listener how you are thinking of the noun.  It is not that the noun requires an article or does not require an article. Your use of the article, or your not using the article, tells the listener whether you have in mind a particular thing or a class of thing.

Studies investigating ROS production in primary T cells are limited, especially  studies of primary human T cells. Moreover, the majority of those studies employed  highly artificial types of stimulation, such as stimulation with PMA and  ionomycin, or with CD3 and CD28 antibodies added to the solution, which lead to T-cell hyperactivation or unresponsiveness, respectively. There were also no precautions taken to discriminate T cell-derived ROS from that emanating from  phagocytic cells, which are always present in preparations of primary T cells and could be easily activated by the same stimulatory agents.

Whenever you are referring to a class or category of something *qua* class or category (a class of study, a class of cells) no determiner is required:

**Studies investigating ROS production

primary human T cells.

highly artificial types of stimulation

stimulation with PMA and ionomycin

PMA

ionomycin**

You're not talking about particular actual molecules of ionomycin but of the drug in general terms.

**Wheels are round.

The wheel was dented.

Gold is a metal.

The gold lay in a heap in the dragon's lair.**

A specific subgroup, on the other hand, requires a determiner:

"*the* majority".

**She wants to sit with the cool kids in the cafeteria.**

**Cool kids around the world know they're cool.**

If you want to  distinguish one class from another:

**We have been speaking of studies of cats and studies of dogs. The studies of cats were conducted by graduate students and the studies of dogs were conducted by Nobel laureates.**

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! However, could you please explain the use of articles in the following sentence from a Nature Reviews article?  _The extreme defects in hair development led the authors to examine whether β-catenin, which is required for **the** formation and homeostasis of hair follicles as part of **the** WNT pathway, is a downstream mediator of ROS in this context._ Isn't  _formation and homeostasis of hair follicles_ a general statement, like _stimulation with PMA and ionomycin_?

Comment: One could conceive of *the formation and homeostasis* as a particular process relating to hair follicles, one of several processes related to follicles; or one could conceive of "formation and homeostasis of hair follicles" as a process in the abstract. Concepts are flexible in that way.  There are several pathways; one of them is known as *the* WNT pathway.  I have to say, I don't know what they mean by "as part of" the WNT pathway, since pathways don't have "parts" -- unless by pathway they mean process, or if by "part" they mean "step".

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my point. It seems, in line also with what J.R. said, these linguistic constructs can be treated as a whole without **the** or split into parts and prefaced with **the**. So, if it is up to the writer to decide, I prefer to omit all **the**s.

Comment: No, the pathway part is clear. I highlighted that **the** mistakenly, sorry. _Pathway_ is singular, and the WNT pathway is indeed one of a kind, so no question about that. Biological signaling pathways indeed have parts - signaling molecules of which pathways are composed. Beta-catenin is one of the molecules that compose the WNT pathway.

Comment: I understand that pathway is singular; but "the" is used because there are many pathways in a biological system, each one doing what it does; this is a *particular* pathway, "the WNT pathway". So there, "the" is not optional.  What I found less than clear was the use of the phrase "a part of"  with the word "pathway".  What are the *parts* of a pathway?  It's a mixed metaphor.

Comment: In fact, the most common way in biology is to say _the member of the pathway_.

Comment: That, too, is a mixed metaphor; mixing metaphors makes things unclear. To process the figurative "pathway" when it is mixed with another metaphor that has nothing to do with "paths" or "ways", we have to translate "pathway" into something like *process involving chemical "messaging"* and then find yet another metaphor for that idea, one to which "member" applies.

Comment: Well, I guess that's just the scientific jargon. I doubt that this expression will change due to linguistic objections ;)